# How to set a unique composite index for a many-to-many join table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I have the following mappings:

```
  <!-- ************* Resource ************************* -->
  <class name="Resource" table="a_resource">
      <id name="resourceId">
          <column name="resource_id" />
          <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      <property name="resourceName" type="string" not-null="true" unique="true">
          <column name="resource_name" />
      </property>
  </class>

  <!-- ************* Group ************************* -->
  <class name="Group" table="a_group">
    <id name="groupId">
      <column name="group_id"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name = "groupName" type="string" not-null="true" unique="true">
      <column name="group_name"/>
    </property>

    <bag name="resources" table="a_group_resource" lazy="false" >
      <key column="group_id"/>
      <many-to-many column="resource_id" class="Resource" />

    </bag>
  </class>
```

This results in a join-table `a_group_resource` with foreign keys `resource_id` & `group_id`.

How can I make hibernate to automatically create a composite unique index on `resource_id` & `group_id` columns so that no two resource_id & group_id combinations can exist in this join table?